# Oracle APEX: Is it possible to programmatically check/uncheck APEX$ROW_SELECTOR for a specific row

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

While looping through the rows of an IG I want to be able to programmatically check row selector for a row where another column's value 'Test'. If it equals something else, I want to uncheck it.
Is that possible?

I have something like that:

```
var model   = this.data.model; 
var records = this.data.selectedRecords;

if (records.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {                          
        test_var = model.getValue (records[i], "FIELD1");
    
        if(test_var=== 'Test'){
            //check the row_selector here

        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect that cell, you'll notice there's a SPAN within the cell. When the row selector is checked, it gets the "is-selected" class added to it.  Might that work for you?

[image]

I can't say I'd know how to reference it, but you're clearly more comfortable with jQuery than I am, so if you work out the method, please share here.